# Why am I getting a missing hash-tags error when I try to run JedisCluster.scan() using a match pattern?

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm trying to run scan on my redis cluster using Jedis. I tried using the `.scan(...)` method as follows for a match pattern but I get the following error:

"JedisCluster only supports SCAN commands with MATCH patterns containing hash-tags"

my code is as follows (excerpted):

```
private final JedisCluster redis;
...
String keyPrefix = "helloWorld:*";
ScanParams params = new ScanParams()
        .match(keyPrefix)
        .count(100);
String cur = SCAN_POINTER_START;

boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    ScanResult<String> resp = redis.scan(cur, params);
    ...
    cur = resp.getStringCursor();
    if (resp.getStringCursor().equals(SCAN_POINTER_START)) {
      done = true;
    }
}
```

When I run my code, it gives a weird error talking about hashtags:
"JedisCluster only supports SCAN commands with MATCH patterns containing hash-tags"

In the redis-cli I could just use match patterns like that what I wrote for the keyPrefix variable. Why am I getting an error?

How do I get Jedis to show me all the the keys that match a given substring?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the redis variable is a RedisCluster object and not a Redis object.

A redis cluster object has a collection of nodes and scanning that is different than scanning an individual node.

To solve the issue, you can scan through each individual node as such:

```
    String keyPrefix = "helloWorld:*";

    ScanParams params = new ScanParams()
        .match(keyPrefix)
        .count(100);

    redis.getClusterNodes().values().stream().forEach(pool -> {
      boolean done = false;
      String cur = SCAN_POINTER_START;
      try (Jedis jedisNode = pool.getResource()) {
        while (!done) {
          ScanResult<String> resp = jedisNode.scan(cur, params);
          ...
          cur = resp.getStringCursor();
          if (cur.equals(SCAN_POINTER_START)) {
            done = true;
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if you have a Master slave relationship you also get the slave records so basically you get duplication. I haven't figured out how to in the scan say "OMIT THE SLAVES RECORDS". As you know in a 3 node cluster it is also a good thing to have a slave replica to take over for Quorum to be met. Yes you can also place the results into a Map and it will automatically remove duplication but that is not the best solution I think since it is already streamed in some way when scanning so duplication should be taken care of.

Comment: By the way I verified this by add another replica to each master and now I get three records: One from Master and another from Slave 1 and another from Slave 2.